# Confidence (scores) values very small

Tags: python-3.x, tensorrt, yolov5

Can you please explain how the if statement scores[i]>0.1 and scores[i]<=1.0 will work?
Because the score values in your output_data is very small (Of the order 10^-3). So, the if condition will never be satisfied.

Comment: Correct. That's how this statement will work.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand. How will the score value be bigger than 0.1?

Comment: I don't know. But the if statement works like that. If scores[i] is larger than 0.1 and smaller than or equal to 1.0 it will be True, otherwise it will be False.